# Azure function proxy failure status in portal

Tags: azure-functions

I have an azure function with an http trigger (named "SigHttpPayloadsUplink")
The function is proxified.

If the function throws an exception, the exception is logged (see the image below), the function call marked as Failed, but the proxy call is marked as "Success" in the portal / AppInsight.

It looks, the proxy erase the failure...

Any idea why?
Thanks for your help.

Thibault.

Here is the logs in AppInsight:
[image]

The proxy conf in proxies.json:

```
    "POST_PayloadsUplink": {
  "matchCondition": {
    "route": "/api/sig/rest/callback/payloads/ul",
    "methods": [
      "POST"
    ]
  },
  "backendUri": "https://localhost/api/SigHttpPayloadsUplink"
},
```

The funciton code:

```
        [FunctionName("SigHttpPayloadsUplink")]
    public static IActionResult Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            SigHttpPayloadsUplink function = new SigHttpPayloadsUplink(req, log);
            return  function.execute();
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            log.LogError(e, "Cannot process message");
            throw new Exception("Pas glop");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. The proxy call's success is determined by whether it was able to route the request.

Even if the underlying function fails, the proxy call was still successful in its job.